# CakePHP 2.0 File Upload, $data has no effect

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

Im working on a site that will enable me to upload files to the server, Im trying to get the file to be renamed to the corresponding mysql id that is inserted with the information.

It kind of works, but every time I upload a file it will re-write over the last file that was uploaded.

This is my code

```
   function uploadFile() {
    $file = $this->data['Upload']['file'];
    $pid = mysql_insert_id();
    if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP.'webroot/files/uploads'.DS."$pid.mp4")) {
            $this->data['Upload']['name'] = $file['name'];
            $this->data['Upload']['eventname'] = $file['evetname'];
            $this->data['Upload']['description'] = $file['description'];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

These are the errors that are occuring on my site,

Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property UploadsController::$data has no effect [APP/Controller/uploads_controller.php, line 58]
Notice (8): Undefined index: eventname [APP/Controller/uploads_controller.php, line 59]
Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property UploadsController::$data has no effect [APP/Controller/uploads_controller.php, line 59]
Notice (8): Undefined index: description [APP/Controller/uploads_controller.php, line 60]
Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property UploadsController::$data has no effect [APP/Controller/uploads_controller.php, line 60]

I don't quite get what is going on really?
Also should I be using the mysqli_insert_id() function instead of mysql_insert_id()? I don't really know how the mysqli_insert_id() works, any help please guys???

Comment: the information from my form however is being inputted into the database, so I don't quite get what it means by $data has no effect, when the data is uploaded to the database. But the file upload is not working as it keeps overwriting the file that is uploaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to manipulate `$this->data` which is read only in Cake 2.0. You should use the new `CakeRequest` object introduced in Cake 2.0.

So `$this->data` becomes: `$this->request->data`.

As for `mysql_insert_id()`, I'm not sure where you are saving data to a database table. Cake stores the `id` of the last inserted record in `$this->ModelName->id`, so you could use that as well.

Comment: Hi I did as you said and now i get these errors,

Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/uploads_controller.php, line 55]
Notice (8): Undefined index: eventname [APP/Controller/uploads_controller.php, line 59]
Notice (8): Undefined index: description [APP/Controller/uploads_controller.php, line 60]
Warning (2): file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/app/tmp/logs/error.log) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE/Cake/Log/Engine/FileLog.php, line 69]

Comment: Im using the mysql_insert_id function as I want the filename of the file uploaded using my form to be renamed as the corresponding field on the SQL table, so if the id number of that entry is 32 then the filename will be renamed to 32.mp4

Comment: The errors you list come from requesting non existing keys in the `$this->request->data` array. You can see what's in the array by putting it inside a `debug()` call. `$this->ModelName->id` is more or less an alias for `mysql_insert_id()`.

Comment: Right instead of using the previous code in order to add data into the sql data I have used this statement,     $this->Upload->save($this->data); which obviously looks at the upload form and saves all data. This works with no errors. BUT...
I have changed the move_uploaded_file line to read this:
f (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP.'webroot/files/uploads'.DS."$this->ModelName->id.mp4"))
This does upload the file but renames it to "->id.mp4" and leaves me with the error......

Comment: Warning (2): file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/app/tmp/logs/error.log) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE/Cake/Log/Engine/FileLog.php, line 69]

Line 69 in filelog.php is:
Warning (2): file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/app/tmp/logs/error.log) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE/Cake/Log/Engine/FileLog.php, line 69]

Not really sure about what this means. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `APP.'webroot/files/uploads'.DS.$this->ModelName->id.'.mp4'`. The other error is related to the fact that your `logs` directory isn't writable. But both problems stem from pretty basic PHP features. You might want to get a bit more aquanted with the basics of PHP before diving into a framework like Cake, which adds another abstraction layer on top of the core language you're writing in.

Comment: i tried that earlier and that didn't work it gives me this error message, Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/uploads_controller.php, line 44]

Comment: You have to substitute "ModelName" for the name of the Model you want to get the last inserted id from.

Comment: ok Ive changed it to $this->Upload->id, I've even used a variation of LastInsertID getInsertID, however this doesn't upload the file to the server, and if it does it re-writes over the file, or just names it 1.mp4, instead of for example 115.mp4, however it does upload the information such as the name and description to the mysql table. i find it strange that this line of code has no effect on the filename

Comment: Without some complete Model and Controller code it's hard to say why you are not getting the last inserted id, but that might merit another question as this question was originally about `$this->data`. As for `move_uploaded_file`, overwriting files with the same name is the intended behaviour as stated in the PHP manual entry for the function.

Comment: I've found the problem the data from the form needs to be saved first before renaming the file to the sql id. i appreciate all your help!